# Windows error when viewing performance tab in computer management

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am running on a fresh install of windows 7 ultimate 64. I have installed all of the drivers from intel(intel DZ68BC mobo). When I open computer management, and click performance tab, I get this error: http://f.cl.ly/items/1N312M1F103B0D26121W/computer_management_performance_tab_error.PNG

Comment: Anything in the system event log?

Comment: Run ProcessMonitor and look for errors (result column) when you start computer management.